Port in personal number
Currently working on an app that makes call to any number using twilio programmable voice but my country does not have any phone number available on the twilio phone number list, is there a way I can port in my own number, because it was very funny when running test to a friend and he was like he was not expecting any call with an international number so he didn't pick. If any one could help, I'd really appreciate it.
I have checked through the twilio doc saw there's an option to port in own number but not documented I think.

There are a few conditions.

you have to be using the US RJ


could you please share more insights.

It seems that you can only port US numbers, see https://help.twilio.com/articles/223179348.
However, if you would just like your recipient to see your number as the caller, you can verify your number as a verified caller ID and use that number in the from field when using the voice API. This requires that you are using the US region. In the Twilio console, under United States (US1) -> Phone Numbers -> Manage -> Verified Caller ID. Add your number there, verify by text and you should be able to use your number in the "from" field and your friend will see your number as the caller.
